# How to upload a recorded audio file to Amazon S3 using jRecorder and Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, audio, amazon-s3

[jRecorder](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder-jquery) is a jQuery plugin for audio recording ([documentation](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/index.html)).  The plugin records an audio file using the browser's flash player and saves the file in a browser temporary file and when the user finishes recording, it sends the file as POST to a PHP server (a php file).  However, I would like to modify the plugin to send the file to an Amazon S3 bucket using Ruby on Rails.

How would I go about sending the recorded file to [my-amazons3-bucket] in RoR?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the host param in the plugin to point to a rails route that will accept the post. Here is AWS Ruby Gem http://amazon.rubyforge.org/

So, you would have a controller that would accept the post and then you would simply upload the posted file to your S3 bucket

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm still not entirely clear what I would need to have in the controller? Would you be able to show a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carrierwave with store option Fog. You will need to initialize your bucket with aws credentials in uploader.

```
 self.storage :fog
    self.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      => 'youraccesskeyid',
      :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yourawssecretaccesskey',
      :region                 => 'yourbucketregion'
    }
    self.fog_directory = "yourbucketname"
```